# I am trying to create a procedure that creates a new row and returns the auto increment id

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb, last-insert-id

the idea id to insert a new row in the table "pag", and get the ID_pag that the new row got

> i have been trying 2 days but all i can get is this error:

- ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 *

  or this one if ";" is removed
- ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 5*

  i am using MariaDB :

Database server

```
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.6-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: cp1252 West European (latin1)
```

Web server

```
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.9
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - 
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.3.9
```

hrere is my code

```
CREATE procedure insertpag (IN `v1` INT(5), IN `v2` CHAR(50), IN `v3` INT(10), IN `v4` CHAR(50))NOT 
DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `tabllename` (`C1`, `c2`, `c3`,`c4`)values(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

Comment: or you could avoid a trivial stored procedure and use [the php API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: This is really not a job for a complicated stored procedure. You'll also want to evaluate where those bizarre numbers in your interface are coming from. Normally you'd use `INT(11)` consistently, not seemingly random values like `INT(10)` or `INT(12)` or the utterly baffling `BIGINT(50)` where that has no way of storing numbers 50 digits long.

Comment: You forget about delimiter re-assign. Now `;` in INSERT INTO code line is perceived as end-of-statement which cause the error.

Comment: thanks for your coments :D.
but:
* I am not useing php, and must not use any tecnologiy that is not already on the scheme 
*because my client is a little paranoid I cant show the real data types and names, but there is 2 numbers ans 2 strings.., i need to return a number.
*i got the same error useing delimiter but it says ..."syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line"...

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't create the procedure with PHP but with the command line client, you need to set a delimiter.

```
> delimiter //
> CREATE PROCEDURE ...
  BEGIN
  END //
> delimiter ;
```

Otherwise I would recommend using the api function `mysqli_insert_id()` instead of making the code difficult to understand and outsource logic to a database server.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, mi first code was right but aparently mi version of database let you select a character to be used as the label "DELIMITER" in the SQL interface.
the default character is ";" so every time I run the process it was actualy executeing

```
CREATE procedure insertpag (IN `USU` BIGINT(50), IN `CON` CHAR(55), IN `Mont` INT(10), IN `ROB` CHAR(55), INOUT `ID` INT(12))NOT 
DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `pag` (`CONCEPT`, `MON`, `USUER_PAG`,`COMPROB`)values(CON, Mont, USU, ROB)delimiter ;
    SET ID = LAST_INSERT_ID()delimiter ;
END
```

and that was the reason for the syntax error.